# confusion in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I have seen in many places different sentences but I don't know which tense is it, I am not sure whether those are sentences or not. The sentences are "Adjectives ending with y" 
"Terrorists killing themselves" 
Which tense is it? Is it a sentence?

Comment: These are not full sentences. The form used in your examples is the present participle, a sort of verbal adjective describing the noun next to it. So, your examples would only appear as headlines or parts of larger sentences: i.e. *this is a list of adjectives ending in y* or *I don't want to watch terrorists killing themselves.*

Answer (score 1):

These are **non-finite** clauses (some see them as phrases) using an **ing-form** for the verb.

Non-finite verbs are not assigned to a tense, and in time they can at times represent past, present and future time, depending on the context, and maingly on the tense of the [finite] verb in the main clause:

*Terrorists **killing** themselves - that **happened** frequently in that part of the world [at that time]*. [**past time**

*Terrorists **killing** themselves - that **happens** frequently in that part of the world [these days]*. [**present time**

*"Terrorists **killing** themselves - this is something that **will not happen** while I'm Prime Minister,*" she said. [**future time**

Comment: Can we call it as a subject in the shape of phrase? For example "adjectives ending with Y are easy to learn."

Comment: 'Adjectives ending with a Y are easy to learn.' - Yes, that is a normal and complete sentence.  The subject of the sentence is 'adjectives'.